# JSON Deserialization for Non-array Property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json, deserialization

I'm new to JSON deserialization and need help with an issue I'm running into.  I created classes that work when all the classes in the JSON are represented as arrays.  However, if you take a close look at the JSON I am required to use you will notice the 'property' member is actual a member of a member and not an array.  This seems to be where my code fails and I think that I am using the wrong 'type' for product in my class definition.

**Here is an example of the JSON:**

```
{
 "kind": "shopping#products",
 "items": 
   [{
   "kind": "shopping#product",
   "id": "tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products/8040/8382012077897342942",
   "product": {
    "googleId": "8382012077897342942",
    "title": "LEGO Star Wars™: Jabba's Palace™ (9516)",
    "description": "Rescue Han Solo from Jabba the Hutt's desert palace!",
    "inventories": [
     {
      "price": 119.99,
      "shipping": 12.95,
      "currency": "USD"
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

**Here is my Code:**

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class g_JSON
    Public Property items As List(Of Items)
End Class

Public Class Items
    Public Property product As List(Of product)
    Public Property kind As String
    Public Property id As String
End Class

Public Class product
    Public Property googleid As String
    Public Property title As String
    Public Inventories As List(Of inventories)
End Class

Public Class inventories
    Public Property price As Double
    Public Property shipping As Double
End Class


Partial Class JSON_Test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub getbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles getbutton.Click

        ' 1. Get JSON string
        Dim google_json_string As String
        google_json_string = json_text.Text


        '2. Deserialize JSON
        Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim ds_results = jss.Deserialize(Of g_JSON)(google_json_string)
        result1.Text = ds_results.items(0).id
        result2.Text = ds_results.items(0).kind
        result3.Text = ds_results.items(0).product(0).title 'errors here

    End Sub
End Class
```

When I try to get a count of product(0) it returns nothing when it should return 1.  If I try to return product(0).title I get the following error:

*Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index*

The message implies nothing is being returned for product.  Any hints or help is greatly appreciated!

P.S.  By the way, when I change the JSON to include product as a parameter[], like below, it works.

```
{
 "kind": "shopping#products",
 "items": 
   [{
   "kind": "shopping#product",
   "id": "tag:google.com,2010:shopping/products/8040/8382012077897342942",
   "product": [{
    "googleId": "8382012077897342942",
    "title": "LEGO Star Wars™: Jabba's Palace™ (9516)",
    "description": "Rescue Han Solo from Jabba the Hutt's desert palace!",
    "inventories": [
     {
      "price": 119.99,
      "shipping": 12.95,
      "currency": "USD"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Comment: You *REALLY* need to learn about the data structures and languages you are working with.  I would suggest learning VB and javascript before you attempt cross-language de/serializations.

Comment: Dan-o, ya I know and I'm trying.  The problem is this item came up out of the blue and I've been trying to cram as much information as possible in a short amount of time to attend to it.  I'll get there eventually and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  I get it.

So in this case its real easy.  The json example at the top of the question indicates that there can only be one product per item.  Your class structure defines a list of products - so deserialization fails.  Change the list to a single product.

If you still have trouble - leave a comment here and we can take a look at it via chat.

This is really too localized a scenario for SO.

Comment: Dan-o, thanks for the help!  I went back and redefined the product class as a single product and that did the trick!  I am now able to dive into the entire structure and pull out the child elements as needed.  I couldn't have done it without you and your insight.